# (moment-timezone). convert time from one timezone to another timezone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am in India, and selecting time 9:00 AM, and timezone eg. 'America/Dawson' and I want to convert time according to selected timezone to 'America/New_York' timezone.But Not getting result

```
    var currentDate = new Date()
    currentDate.setHours(9, 0, 0);
    moment.tz.setDefault('America/Dawson')
    var currentDateMom = moment(currentDate)
    var oldTimezoneTime = currentDateMom.tz('America/New_York').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ');
    console.log(oldTimezoneTime)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the [`moment.tz`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) constructor to create our moment object with the correct year, month, day, hour etc values.

This will create a moment date in the `America/Dawson` timezone with the date set to the current date and time to 09:00.

We can then use the [`.tz()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) function to convert to the new timezone (`America/New_York`)

```js
function getTimeInTimezone(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, timeZone) {
    // Construct using an array of date elements...
    const dateArr = [year, month, day, hour, minute, second];
    return moment.tz(dateArr, timeZone);
}

const now = new Date()

const year = now.getFullYear();
const month = now.getMonth();
const day = now.getDate();
const hour = 9;

const originalTimeZone = 'America/Dawson';
const newTimeZone = 'America/New_York';

const timeInOriginalTimeZone = getTimeInTimezone(year, month, day, hour, 0, 0, originalTimeZone);
const timeInNewTimeZone = moment(timeInOriginalTimeZone).tz(newTimeZone);

console.log('Timezone'.padEnd(20), 'Time');
console.log(originalTimeZone.padEnd(20), timeInOriginalTimeZone.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
console.log(newTimeZone.padEnd(20), timeInNewTimeZone.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before access a particular timezone, you need to load it like so,

```
moment.tz.add('Europe/Berlin|CET CEST CEMT|-10 -20 -30')
```

after adding use this format

```
moment(date).tz('Europe/Berlin').format(format)
```

[Zone Add format](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/packed/latest.json)

Comment: How I will get this pattern `('Europe/Berlin|CET CEST CEMT|-10 -20 -30')` for each timezone

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
import moment from "moment-timezone";
    
const now = moment(); // Create a moment object representing the current date and time
      const nowInNY = now.tz("America/New_York"); // Convert the moment object to Eastern Timezone
      const formattedTime = nowInNY.format("hh:mm A"); // Format the time as "12-hour format" with AM/PM indicator
      console.log("value", formattedTime)
```